# Langchain create_csv_agent with streamlit file_uploader: raise ValueError(f"Expected str or list, got {type(path)}")

Tags: streamlit, openai-api, langchain

I am using streamlit to upload and read simple csv file with streamlit file uploader, but I keep getting '    raise ValueError(f"Expected str or list, got {type(path)}")
' on langchain's create_csv_agent

```
from langchain.agents import create_csv_agent
from langchain.llms import OpenAI
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import streamlit as st


def main():
    load_dotenv()
    st.set_page_config(page_title="Ask your CSV ", page_icon="")
    st.header("Ask your CSV")
    user_csv = st.file_uploader("Upload a CSV file", type="csv")
    
    if user_csv is not None:    
        # st.write(user_csv.read())
        # import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
        

        llm = OpenAI(temperature=0)
        agent = create_csv_agent(llm, user_csv.read(), verbose=True)
        user_question = st.text_input("Ask your question")

        if user_question is not None and user_question != "":
            response = agent.run(user_question)
            st.write(response)




if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

once a csv is uploaded, a value error is raised.

I tried parsing the file name. I am expecting to read the file and ask questions about it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you're reading in the CSV file using `user_csv.read()` which will return a string. Instead, it's recommended to use Pandas' `read_csv()` to read the contents of the CSV file.

In your case, replace `user_csv.read()` with `pd.read_csv(user_csv)`.

Hope this helps!